# How to merge two queries into a subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have database like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e52c43

**First query** is :

```
SELECT m.tanggal, sum(mi.qty) as totalMuatan, mi.idPlastik 
FROM tblMuatan m
LEFT JOIN tblMuatanIsi mi ON m.idMuatan = mi.idMuatan
WHERE m.tanggal='2020-03-15'
GROUP BY mi.idPlastik
```

The result is:

```
tanggal       totalMuatan    idPlastik
2020-03-15    85             1
2020-03-15    10             2
```

And **second query** is :

```
SELECT s.tanggal, sum(si.qty) as totalStok, si.idPlastik

FROM tblStok s

LEFT JOIN tblStokIsi si ON s.idStok = si.idStok
WHERE s.tanggal = '2020-03-15'
GROUP BY si.idPlastik
```

The result is :

```
tanggal       totalStok    idPlastik
2020-03-15    100          1
2020-03-15    200          2
```

I want to merge that 2 queries into single query with subquery

```
tanggal       totalStok     totalMuatan     netTotal    idPlastik
2020-03-15    100           85              15          1
2020-03-15    200           10              190         2
```

How to do the subquery in example above? Thank you for the support

Comment: UNION ALL, GROUP BY tanggal.

Comment: Do you want only matching "idPlastik: to display from both table ? If YES then inner join will work. If NO then you might need to used Left Join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use `COALESCE` since you're using `LEFT JOIN` for the tables you are calculating `SUM` from to avoid no result for the records that have `NULL` values.

```
select m.tanggal, t.totalStok, sum(mi.qty) as totalMuatan, coalesce(t.totalStok,0)-coalesce(sum(mi.qty),0) as netTotal, mi.idPlastik 
from tblMuatan m
LEFT JOIN tblMuatanIsi mi ON m.idMuatan = mi.idMuatan
JOIN (SELECT s.tanggal, sum(si.qty) as totalStok, si.idPlastik 
FROM tblStok s 
LEFT JOIN tblStokIsi si ON s.idStok = si.idStok 
WHERE s.tanggal='2020-03-15'
GROUP BY s.tanggal,si.idPlastik) t on m.tanggal=t.tanggal and mi.idPlastik = t.idPlastik 
group by  m.tanggal, t.totalStok,mi.idPlastik
```

Comment: I tried your query, but it return unknown column mi.idPlastik. I've moved the tblMuatanIsi left join to above tblMuatan, but still give an error. Please help me to fix that. Thanks!

Comment: @Goldplate That's my bad. You don't actually need join on idPlastik. I corrected it, it should work now

Comment: The return is incorrect http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e52c43/50 as shown here.

Comment: This works now. Needed to understand relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry for late acceptance. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.tanggal, 
       b.totalstok, 
       a.totalmuatan, 
       ( totalstok - totalmuatan ) netTotal, 
       a.idplastik 
FROM   (SELECT convert(varchar, m.tanggal, 23) tanggal, 
               Sum(mi.qty) AS totalMuatan, 
               mi.idplastik 
        FROM   #tblmuatan m 
               LEFT JOIN #tblmuatanisi mi 
                      ON m.idmuatan = mi.idmuatan 
        WHERE  m.tanggal = 1 
        GROUP  BY mi.idplastik, 
                  convert(varchar, m.tanggal, 23)) a 
       JOIN (SELECT convert(varchar, s.tanggal, 23) tanggal, 
                    Sum(si.qty) AS totalStok, 
                    si.idplastik 
             FROM   #tblstok s 
                    LEFT JOIN #tblstokisi si 
                           ON s.idstok = si.idstok 
             WHERE  s.tanggal = 1 
             GROUP  BY si.idplastik, 
                       convert(varchar, s.tanggal, 23)) b 
         ON a.idplastik = b.idplastik
```

Comment: Why this query return syntax error? Please help me to fix that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But if I have 3 row of tblPlastik, the 3rd data is not showing instead of giving '0' or NULL return. How to fix that? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Please try..

```
SELECT T1.tanggal, T2.totalStok, T1.totalMuatan, (T2.totalStok - T1.totalMuatan), T1.idPlastik
FROM
(SELECT m.tanggal, sum(mi.qty) as totalMuatan, mi.idPlastik 
FROM tblMuatan m
LEFT JOIN tblMuatanIsi mi ON m.idMuatan = mi.idMuatan
WHERE m.tanggal='2020-03-15'
GROUP BY mi.idPlastik) 
as T1,
(SELECT s.tanggal, sum(si.qty) as totalStok, si.idPlastik
FROM tblStok s
LEFT JOIN tblStokIsi si ON s.idStok = si.idStok
WHERE s.tanggal = '2020-03-15'
GROUP BY si.idPlastik)
as T2
WHERE
T1.tanggal = T2.tanggal;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Note that if one of the two queries doesn't return anything, this solution will not return the existing data.

Comment: @jarlh Please provide me link, so that I can follow the modern join you are mentioning. Any study or blog link. Thanks !

Comment: @jarlh Apologies! bothering you again. Please provide me specific to the join you are mentioning. This wiki is too big, and has got all the joins ! Thanks again!

Comment: Simply do `select ... from t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.c = t2.d`, instead of `select ... from t1, t2 where t1.c = t2.d`.